# change nodevalue with all childnodes in domelement

Tags: php, domdocument

I have html code something like this:

```
<p><i>i_text</i>,p_text</p>
```

*i_text*,p_text

i want change all node values in this domelement and keep all tags

*i_changed_text*,p_changed_text

my attempts)

```
$html = '<p><i>i_text</i> p_text</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $element->nodeValue = str_replace('_','_changed_',$element->nodeValue);
}
echo($dom->saveHTML());
```

output

i_changed_text,p_changed_text

this code return correct text but don't save childnodes

```
$html = '<p><i>i_text</i>,p_text</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
$elem = $dom->createElement('dfn', 'tag');
$attr = $dom->createAttribute('text');
$attr->value = 'element';
$elem->appendChild($attr);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    while ($element->hasChildnodes()) {
        $element = $element->childNodes->item(0);
    }
    $changed_value = str_replace('_','_changed_',$element->nodeValue);
    $element->nodeValue = str_replace("tag", $dom->saveXML($elem), $changed_value);
}
echo ($dom->saveXML());
```

output

*i_changed_text*,p_text

this code save and change values in childnodes but don't change text in parentnode

Answer (score 0):

my solution)

*i_text*,p_text**,a_text**,another one_text

```
$html = '<p><i>i_text</i>,p_text<b>,a_text</b>,another one_text</p>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->validateOnParse = true;
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if($element->hasChildnodes()==true && $element->parentNode->nodeName == '#document'){
        foreach($element->childNodes as $element_child){
            $element_child->nodeValue = str_replace('_','_changed_', $element_child->nodeValue);
        }
    }
}
echo ($dom->saveXML());
```

output

*i_changed_text*,p_changed_text**,a_changed_text**,another one_changed_text